# SQL group by count unique values into separate columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two columns, `a` and `b`, and both have categorical values. Say the database looks like this,

```
a    b
a1   b1
a2   b2
a3   b1
......
```

I want to group by `a` and count unique values of `b` into separate columns, for example,

```
Value    b1    b2    b3
a1       5     10    3
a2       4     6     7
....
```

I tried `SELECT a, b, count(b) FROM table GROUP BY a, b` and got something similar like this:

```
a1    b1    5
a1    b2    10
....
```

What's the SQL query to produce the desired output? Thanks.

Comment: Please specify which database engine is used. Also, search for _pivoting_ in _sql_ which should answer your question.

Comment: @ShriramRamesh - I am using BigQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT
  a,
  COUNTIF(b = 'b1') AS b1,
  COUNTIF(b = 'b2') AS b2,
  COUNTIF(b = 'b3') AS b3
FROM t
GROUP BY a
-- ORDER BY a
```

Answer (score 3):

You can perform conditional addition. For example:

```
select
  a,
  sum(case when b = 'b1' then 1 else 0 end) as b1,
  sum(case when b = 'b2' then 1 else 0 end) as b2,
  sum(case when b = 'b3' then 1 else 0 end) as b3
from t
group by a
order by a
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach to achieve would be:

```
Select a, 
count(CASE WHEN b = 'b1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) b1,
count(CASE WHEN b = 'b2' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) b2,
count(CASE WHEN b = 'b2' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) b3
from table
group by a
order by 1
```